# Maven central repository: Any friendly way to browse artifacts?

Tags: maven, navigation, repository, usability, maven-central

I'm new to maven. Now I'm learning how to find and use libraries from maven repository. I see the maven central repository (mcr) as similar to cpan, just mcr is for java and cpan is for perl.

I see a big difference between mcr and cpan: When I search for something (for example "ssh") in the [cpan web](http://www.cpan.org/), I get a brief description of the packages found (what they are and what they do). And if I click on the packages link, then I get the full description (name, sypnosis, description, examples, etc).

Now, if I search for something (for example "ssh") in the [mcr web](http://search.maven.org/), I get the list of artifacts found, their groupid, version and date, but there is no description on what an artifact is or what it does. Even if I click on the links (version link is the only one that gives some information), I don't get any description on what it is or what it does or examples.

Is there any way (i.e. some other page) to **browse the repository artifacts in a more friendly way**? (something similar to cpan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/) website.

It is linked to the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/), and provides a more detailed view for each of the artifacts - including descriptions*.

So for example for the [`commons-httpclient`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient) artifact it has the following description:

> The HttpClient component supports the client-side of RFC 1945 (HTTP/1.0) and RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1) , several related specifications (RFC 2109 (Cookies) , RFC 2617 (HTTP Authentication) , etc.), and provides a framework by which new request types (methods) or HTTP extensions can be created easily.

***Note**, the descriptions shown are taken from the `<description>` tag from the artifact's [pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html). This tag is optional, which means not every project actually defines it, so unfortunately you might not always see a description.

Comment: Thank you, it is not perfect, but is better than nothing. The most useful thing to me is the description that appears under each artifact in a the result list of a search. It allows me to quickly discard not desired artifacts, and to know what artifacts could be interesting. Same as in cpan, when I click on an artifact link from the result list, a detailed page is shown (description, tags and versions). Main missing thing: The detailed page should contain a link to the documentation of the artifact (for example, the documentation generated automatically with the "mvn site" command).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Bintray's jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter). It is a superset of Maven Central and adds metadata on packages, such as author, license, description, release notes, ratings and reviews etc. You can also register to get updates on version releases.

Comment: Unfortunately our proxy is black-listing that page :-(